# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes

Tags: java, encryption

I am encrypting my symmetric key (AES) With RSA Private key and decrypting the same with my public key.

But when I encrypt the data the byte length is 16 bytes however, when I decrypt the data it throws the subjected error and the length of byte data is 344 at the time of decryption.

can someone suggest what is wrong in my approach?

**Encryption Code**

```
 public static String encrypt(byte[] data, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(data));
    }
```

**Decryption Code**

```
public static String decrypt(byte[] data, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        System.out.println(data.length);
        return new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipher.doFinal(data)));
    }
```

**Calling mechanism**

```
CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream file1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\imjme1\\Desktop\\Work_backup\\FMS\\EPM_FILE_ENCRYPTION\\NIFT_SOLUTION\\Certificate_KeyStore\\cdcCert.cer");
            Certificate[] chain = { fact.generateCertificate(file1) };
            file1.close();  // or use try-with-resources

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );  
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\\\Users\\\\imjme1\\\\Desktop\\\\Work_backup\\\\FMS\\\\EPM_FILE_ENCRYPTION\\\\NIFT_SOLUTION\\\\Certificate_KeyStore\\\\senderKeystore.jks");
            keyStore.load( is, "fms123".toCharArray() );

PrivateKey privateKey = ( PrivateKey ) keyStore.getKey( "CDC", "fms123".toCharArray() );
            PublicKey publicKey= null;
            if (privateKey instanceof PrivateKey) {
                // Get certificate of public key
                Certificate cert = keyStore.getCertificate("CDC");
                // Get public key
                publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();


              }


            KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            generator.init(128); // The AES key size in number of bits
            SecretKey secKey = generator.generateKey();

            String e =  encrypt( secKey.getEncoded() , privateKey);

            PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter( new File("C:\\Users\\imjme1\\Desktop\\Work_backup\\FMS\\EPM_FILE_ENCRYPTION\\NIFT_SOLUTION\\Certificate_KeyStore\\tet.txt") );
         w.write(e);
         w.close();
          //  encrypt(secKey.getEncoded(), privateKey);
            Path fileLocation = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\imjme1\\Desktop\\Work_backup\\FMS\\EPM_FILE_ENCRYPTION\\NIFT_SOLUTION\\Certificate_KeyStore\\tet.txt");
//            
//            
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(fileLocation);
            String d = decrypt(  data , publicKey);

System.out.println(d);
            System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: "what is wrong in my approach?" You're using the wrong keys. Use the public key for encryption, and the private key for decryption. The public key is assumed to be known by everyone, and you don't want everyone to be able to decrypt.

Comment: Actually, I am bound to encrypt it with private key; also, i used bouncy castle first to use private key as encryption and it worked. I dont know why its throwing error in this code. Can you please tell me any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue by Base64 Encoder/decoder

```
   public static String encrypt(byte[] data, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(data));
    }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] data, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        System.out.println(data.length);// it was 344 here

        byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);
        byte[] todecrypt = cipher.doFinal(decoded);

        System.out.println(decoded.length);// it become 256

        String finalstring = new String( todecrypt, "UTF-8" );
        return finalstring;
    }
```